# Better way to design code structure of many singletons

Tags: c++, singleton, structure

I have many classes designed like **below** and they have to be accessible everywhere at any time (also just as a single instance). Currently Ive done that using a namespace which stores pointer to all classes. Is there any better way to solve/design such problems/structures?

```
// AbcManager.h
class AbcManager
{
public:
    void printTest();

private:
    char text[] = "Hello world";
}

// ManagerNamespace.h
namespace Manager
{
    AbcManager* abc;
}

// somewhere.h
{
    Manager::abc->printTest();
}
```

Comment: Many singletons - it is an oxymoron, is it not?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do they need to be accessed everywhere?

Comment: Since they are all singletons, can you make a single "big" class as single singleton?

Comment: @Katianie for example a FailHandler which has to deal with fatal errors (important)

Comment: You can probably look into the Service Locator pattern. It pretty much does what you want.

Comment: There couldn't be need for something like `FailHandler` to be accessible from anywhere. There is also no need for a separate namespace to hold singleton instance pointer - just make it a static field.

Comment: @VTT i have a need for such a one because such an error is changing the program flow and more, additionally there are othere classes like one that is providing paths

Comment: I will repeat my question: since there is a single instance for every singleton, what benefit do you gain from making several singletons instead of a single manager singleton class, with all the functions and attributes you need? Depending on your answer there might be better solutions.

Comment: This is not a singleton. It is just a global pointer. A singleton cannot be created twice, you can make as many `AbcManager` objects as you want.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Singleton should only provide a global access to some object. Restricting objects count (as in classic singleton definition) is a direct violation of single responsibility principle that brings nothing but trouble.

Comment: @Attersson readability and SRP

Comment: @VTT I agree, which is why you should avoid them. But singletons are not singletons unless they are singular. This object is not singular, there just happens to be only one of them. The question should be how can i avoid code structure of global pointers to managers. Although global access is a specialization of the concept of singleton, it doesn't even need to have that.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox Well, I don't agree... (1) There is no need to avoid singletons since it is a valid optimization technique. (2) Amount of objects of class managed by singleton could be unrestricted (for example singleton `std::string`). Singleton should only provide a global access point to a one of those object. Or (alternative view) class restricting number of simultaneously existing objects should not be called singleton (and that number is not necessary 1).

Comment: @VTT [`the singleton pattern is a software design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). I agree that global manager can be useful, and the manager can manage several objects, there can even be several managers. But they are not singletons then. They are objects that you are using in the global scope. Singleton also has nothing to do with global access, although that is almost always how it is implemented.

Comment: @Phins While readability is arbitrary, I find the point about SRP controversial too. You would allocate a few singletons basing on calls (RAII) but this means every call constructs and deconstructs (when the function terminates) some singleton. Then the overall namespace solution seems very, very flawed because it still contains pointers "accessible from everywhere".

Comment: @FantasticMrFox I prefer original singleton definition *"Ensure a class only has one instance, and provide a global point of access to it."* from "Design Patterns". As I mentioned earlier, it does not make sense to create a generic class that limits number of simultaneously excising objects to 1. Such class typically can be easily extended to restrict count to any number, so it does not make sense to use a special name "Singleton" for a particular variant of this class restricting number to 1. So I prefer to call "singleton" only classes implementing second part - that is global access point.

Comment: @VTT The book does say that, but it's suggested implementation also is a design that insures a single instance. The very first line is this: `Ensuring a unique instance. The Singleton pattern makes the sole instance a normal instance of a class, but that class is written so that only one instance can ever be created.`

Comment: I think you can also do it like this:- `static AbcManager* abc;`. Is this what you meant? You can then call it like this:- `abc->printTest();`. But no one is encouraged to use the static keyword unless they are going to change the values assigned to the whole class, anything changed in that static variable will affect all the members related to that particular class.

Comment: @VTT Without being singular, a singleton is just a global. Having a global access point is just a nice to have in a singleton. I think you should consider a new name for what you think of as a Singleton, because having a global access point, is just a .. global.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox I think the name "Singleton" is more suitable for "global point of access provider" because number 1 is at least present in it somehow: 1 global point of access to 1 instance. While special case of "simultaneously existing class instances count restricted" that restricts instances count to 1 hardly deserves a name on it own because such a case is quire rare.

Comment: @VTT, Every source quoted so far in this conversation has singularity of the object (as in only 1 instance) as part of the definition **and** the suggested implementation. Its fine, to call it anything you want in your own space, but in terms of formal definitions, everywhere i can find says it will be a single object. [Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1921/Singleton-Pattern-its-implementation-with-C) is another one if you want: `To create only one instance of a class in a truly object oriented fashion by adhering to the basic principles of object oriented programming`

Comment: @FantasticMrFox My primary point is that usual singleton definitions are misleading and / or tend to violate SRP principle. So the usual story is that someone writes something like Meyers' singleton first and then ends up writing whining articles regarding singletons being evil or singletons being bad for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Two requisites are demanded:

- SRP
- Readability

After giving some careful thought it is clear that SRP is not an issue, since, as OP stated:

> they have to be accessible everywhere at any time

Which means there is absolutely no need to have separate objects. If the namespace stores all the pointers, but the initialization of different objects is done stack-wise? At any time, some might be missing, pointing to null. Which only leaves the following trivial possibilities:

- With no information hiding: Nested namespaces wrapping static functions and variables.
- With information hiding: Single 'big' singleton manager class. For additional readability, use prefixes in the name of variables and member functions.
- Keep what you already have

I would recommend making the distinction between a singleton (object that can have only a single instance) and a normal object which gets instantiated only once by your code (the latter is not a singleton).

Answer (score -2):

Would a template be a good fit, considering you have "many classes designed like below". Just instantiate each template with the type/nontype parameter you need. Not sure if this is what you're asking though.